# Android Wear - Start App voice command not working

Tags: wear-os

I have an app installed on Android Wear Emulator that I can directly run from Start->MyApp. However when I want to start it with voice command i.e. Start MyApp, it keeps waiting for something but does not complete. What could be reason for this?

[image]

Comment: The only thing I can say now is that this works fine on a real device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a limitation of the current emulator that it does not support voice actions via the keyboard, even though the text appears on the display. You will need to start the application by clicking on the display, then the red G, and then going to the start menu and picking the app from there. You can also quickly start the application using something like this from your development machine:

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.android.test/.TestActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

The watch needs to be connected to a phone (device or emulator) with an internet connection for the voice commands to work.

Comment: Yes, I have a working Internet connection on  Phone. Strangely, "Voice actions" on the Android Wear app installed on the phone are also not working. Dev Tools and Speech Recgnition Applications on the wear get closed with an error when I launch them from "Start".

Comment: I tried it also multiple times it never worked for me.

Comment: @rekire I will really appreciate if you can share anything related on this issue in future.